# Using either x-roots or logarithms to simplify equation

Tags: logarithms, roots

I have the equation:

$.5 = 1-(1-s^r)^b$

And want to solve for $s$.

Would the correct solution involve (1) b-roots and r-roots or (2) logarithms?

Here's approach (1):

[image]

Here's approach (2):

[image]

Approach (1) seems to be less messy algebraically, but beyond that am I missing something that makes one approach better (or more correct) than the other?

Comment: Both approaches seem fine. For many purposes I prefer the log approach, since it involves familiar functions and may make estimates easier.

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything.  When I teach Calc I, I teach my students both of these approaches.

- Compare the following four equations: $2^x=b$, $x^b=e$, $x^by^c=f(y)$, and your equation.  To be solved algebraically: in the first case, you have to take log$_2$; in the second case, you have to raise to $1/b$ power; in third case, you have to divide by $y^c$; in your case, you have to take a root.  And it's hard for first-time students to figure out which one to do when.
- The log approach, however, is failsafe.  One approach works for all four types of equations.  The drawback is, log is much slower than the algebraic approach.
- When you get to logarithmic differentiation, most of those problems can be solved without log as well (e.g., $x^x=e^{x\log x}$; then use chain rule to differentiate).  However, logarithmic differentiation is often taught just because it's one uniform approach that works for all types of problems, including $(x+2)^2(x+1)^3(x-3)^4$.